# How to create obfuscatable variables and functions in a javascript module?

Tags: javascript, module, obfuscation

I have a set of js files I concatenate into a unique file at compile time, before running YUI compressor on it (all under maven).

Unfortunately, the content of a file is not obfuscated. It is as if all declared variables and methods were considered public (and therefore not obfuscatable).

For example `a.js` uses methods declared in `b.js`. The content of the concatenated file is:

```
(function() {

    // b.js' content...

    // a.js' content...
    (function() {

        // Some var and methods of a declared here

        $(document).ready(function(){

            // Calls some a.js and b.js methods
            ...

        });

    })();

})();
```

The functions and variables of `b.js` are defined as following in the `b.js` file:

```
var B1 = "Some text";
var B2 = "More text";
...

function MyPrivateMethod1() { ... };
function MyPrivateMethod2() { ... };
```

The methods of `a.js` are obfuscated, but not those of `b.js`. I can see `B1`, `B2`, `MyPrivateMethod1`, `MyPrivateMethod1`... in the concatenated file, but I cannot find the variables and methods of `a.js` (the names have been obfuscated).

How can I obfuscate the var and methods of `b.js` in the concatenated file? (REM: I need to keep `b.js` as a separate file).

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why would one want to obfuscate?

Comment: Why not pack content of a.js and b.js to a closure or use name spacing pattern to deal with global variables?

Comment: @RoToRa - [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291672/why-obfuscate-code)

Comment: @Wojciech How do I pack content of a.js and b.js to a closure? (Sorry, I am still new to Javascript)

Comment: @RoToRa I want to make it a pain for those who want to still some code and I am ok to pay the price in readability.

Comment: I misunderstand your question. I thought the problem is in variable scope, that you have the same names in both files. Sorry mate.

Comment: @Wojciech No worry. In fact, your suggestion led me to read more about closure and name spacing, which led me to understand Javascript scope better, which led me to craft my solution. Now, it works super fine. It was just a matter of making stuff private in a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, but I am not sure it is the best one. I moved `b.js`'s code in a function:

```
var dummy = function() {

    var B1 = "Some text";
    var B2 = "More text";
    ...

    var MyPrivateMethod1 = function() { ... };
    var MyPrivateMethod1 = function() { ... };
    ...

    function MyPublicMethod1() { ... };
    function MyPublicMethod2() { ... };
    ...

}
```